# Execute function at specific GMT time daily

Tags: python, time

How can I implement what is described in the tittle in python, regardless of when the initial script will be run?
For example if I run the script at 2 am in a `"GMT +2"` timezone or at 8 pm at a `"GMT -1"` timezone, this script must schedule a function to run every day at `GMT 00:00`.

Comment: You have to get your timezone first, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Cron job? `sched`? Have you tried *anything*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is check the time difference that your 'x' time zone has with the GMT 00:00 one. Then find the corresponding time in your time zone using that difference, lets name it 'adjusted_time_to_my_timezone' , and use python to create a cron job to run at this 'adjusted_time_to_my_timezone'

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `strftime` and `gmtime` (GMT):

```
from time import strftime, gmtime
def foo():
    if strftime("%H%M", gmtime()) == "0000": # Gets time in this format: HHMM
        # Do stuff
```

For more information, go to [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) (Python docs).

Comment: i didn't, someone else did